# GUI appears twice in my app

Tags: java, android, user-interface, double

I'm writing my very first android app and has finally managed to get my program to show up on the AVD. However, the GUI seems to appear twice in the same window. The first on above the other.

it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xK1S.png

my main activity looks like this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.xsiand.something.StartingPoint$PlaceholderFragment" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text="Your name:"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameField"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/save" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your name is: "
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my only class like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StartingPoint extends Activity {

    private String name;
    private Button saveButton;
    private TextView display;
    private EditText nameInput;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        name = null;
        nameInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameField);
        saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);  

        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResult);


        nameInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                //also what to put here in order to get the keyboard to appear?

            }
        });

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(nameInput.getText().toString() != null){
                    name = nameInput.getText().toString();
                    display.setText("Your name is: " + name);
                }
                else
                    display.setText("noname");
            }
        });

    }

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Finally my manifest looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xsiand.something"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".StartingPoint"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Why is the gui showing up twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding PlaceholderFragment in your activity.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

And PlaceholderFragment is inflating the same layout as your activity

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer!

Comment: I guess you have created the default activity with fragment from eclipse. I suggest you to read about fragment.

Comment: Basically a fragment is a reusable component than can be part of any activity. in your case you were creating an activity with a layout and adding a fragment with the same layout to that activity layout. btw can you set the answer in so ?